# Как сбросить эффект от Pinch в js?

Tags: javascript, вёрстка, mobile-web, touch-event, zoom

Собственно вопрос:
В мобильном браузере(например safari под ios), при Pinch-е происходит увеличение страницы. Нужно сбросить этот эффект по требованию из js, точнее нужно сделать так чтобы в области видимости была вся страница(в ширину).
Нужно именно сбросить эффект, а не запретить его.
Не первый день мучаюсь, помогите?

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо подписаться на событие touch и останавливать его

```
function touchEvent(e){
 if(e.touches.length > 1){
     //Тут можно проверять изменение scale значения страницы и останавливать событие
     e.preventDefault()
 }
}
```

Также ознакомьтесь с [gestureevent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkitjs/gestureevent) Gesture events - содержат информацию о scale и rotation события.

Comment: Я же писал выше. Мне не нужно запрещать этот эффект, мне нужно его сбросить при необходимости.

Comment: Так я вам и дал ответ, вы допишите условие при котором не будете сбрасывать. Вашу задачу еще можно сформулировать так: Остановить поведение pinch eventá по условию. Вот повесьте слушатель, добавьте в него условие при котом останавливать event и наслаждайтесь. Как итог событие будет остановлено по нужному вам условию.

Comment: Не совсем так. Дело в том что нужно сбросить эффект уже после того как он применился, а не во время его совершения.

Comment: Все тоже самое, только вы ещё проверяете окончание события и изменился ли в нем scale, если все ок, откатываете scale назад. События на touchend есть.

Comment: как "откатить scale назад"?

Comment: C помощью манипуляций с meta viewport
document.querySelector('meta[name=viewport]').setAttribute('content', 'width='+width+',minimum-scale=0,maximum-scale=10,initial-scale='+scale);

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62851/discussion-between-errorman-and-dstrokov).